# What does closing an invalid file descriptor do?

Tags: c, file-io

I have some legacy code that does this all over the place:

```
int fd; // open a file 

if(fd == -1)
{
    close(fd);
}
```

This looks very wrong to me.

Is closing an invalid file descriptor valid?

Comment: *This looks very wrong to me.*  Agreed.  The "thinking" behind that code must have been ... interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to manual:

> Upon successful completion, a value of 0 is returned.  Otherwise, a
>   value
>        of -1 is returned and the global integer variable errno is set to indicate the error.

and then:

> ```
>  The close() system call will fail if:
>
>  [EBADF]            fildes is not a valid, active file descriptor.
> ```

Then nothing harmful will happen.

Answer (score 5):

It returns an error code.There is nothing *wrong* but it is not useful either, as there is no check made on the `return` value anyway.

Quoting the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close)

> **Return Value**
>
> `close()` returns zero on success. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

and

> **Errors**
>
> `EBADF`
> `fd` isn't a valid open file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

note that in windows msvc, calling close with an invalid fd causes an abort() to occur by means of an assertion. the fd is checked it is greater than or equal to 0 and less than some magic number "nhandle" (which has the value of 64 on my system) not even an exception you can catch, or returning -1. it just bombs.

you'll get something like this (screenshot thanks to one of the users of my library):

[image]